# Link working on Viualforce but not on Salesforce Site

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com-sites, url

I have this code on a VF page

```
<apex:dataTable value="{!List_of_images}" var="The_list">
    <apex:column headerValue="Pic" styleClass="P_image" value=""/>
    <apex:column styleClass="P_image">
        <apex:facet name="header">Pic</apex:facet>
        <a href="{!The_list.LINK_IN_DB}" target="_blank"><apex:outputField value="{!The_list.Pic_in_db}"/></a>
    </apex:column>
</apex:dataTable>
```

It works perfectly, but when I publish the Visualforce Page on a Force.com Site, it doesn't work. What could be issue?

Controller

```
public with sharing class GetRecords {
    public List<Contact> ContactList {get;set;}

    public GetRunningRecords() {
        ContactList = [ SELECT Name, Pic_in_db__c, LINK_IN_DB__c FROM Contact];
    }
}
```

Strangely enough when I inspect element, I don't see the value from {!The_list.LINK_IN_DB}, I just see

```
  <a href target="_blank">
```

Sample URLs that I'm using include https://www.facebook.com/ & https://twitter.com/

I slightly altered code to this

```
 <apex:column styleClass="P_image">
      <apex:facet name="header">Pic</apex:facet>
           <apex:outputLink value="https://login.salesforce.com/?locale=eu" id="theLink"><apex:outputField value="{!The_list.Pic_in_db}"/></apex:outputLink>
 </apex:column>
```

It works, but when I put in the URL from the controller as the value like this....

```
 <apex:outputLink value="{!The_list.LINK_IN_DB}" id="theLink"><apex:outputField value="{!The_list.Pic_in_db}"/></apex:outputLink>
```

It doesn't work. Pretty much scratching my hair out at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if your site's Guest User has access to the object your controller is querying on the database. If it isn't visible (the user doesn't have the `read` permission), the visitors can't access it.